# babel georgian and fontspec

Tags: fontspec, babel

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[georgian]{babel}
\usepackage{ifxetex}% load different packages with/without XeLaTex
\ifxetex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{sylfaen.ttf}
\else  % packages below are not needed with utf8 based engines
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T8M]{fontenc}
\fi%

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}

test ტესტი

\end{abstract}

\section{Test section}
test ტესტი
\end{document}
```

For `pdflatex` everything works...when i have active language `georgian` georgian text is not displayed...I know fontencoding is changed from EU1/2 to TU, but don't know why EU1/2 is activated but not TU...

Just switching from EU to TU in ldf file does not help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `georgian.ldf` hasn't been updated to support `TU`. The workaround is easy:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[georgian]{babel}

\usepackage{ifxetex}% load different packages with/without XeLaTex

\ifxetex
  \def\georgianencoding{TU}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\else  % packages below are not needed with utf8 based engines
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T8M]{fontenc}
\fi


\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}

test ტესტი

\end{abstract}

\section{Test section}
test ტესტი
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's an edited version of `georgian.ldf` (just the relevant part):

```
\newif\if@kauni@ode
\ifdefined\luatexversion \@kauni@odetrue \else
\ifdefined\XeTeXrevision \@kauni@odetrue \fi\fi
\ifx\l@georgian\@undefined
  \@nopatterns{Georgian}
  \adddialect\l@georgian0
\fi
\def\@setgeorgianencoding{%
  \def\sce@a##1##2{%
    \edef\sce@b{##1}%
    \edef\sce@c{##2}%
    \ifx\sce@b\sce@c
      \let\georgiancoding\sce@c
    \fi}%
  \def\cdp@elt##1##2##3##4{%
    \sce@a{##1}{T8K}%
    \sce@a{##1}{T8M}%
    \if@kauni@ode
      \sce@a{##1}{TU}%TU
    \fi}%
  \cdp@list
}
\@setgeorgianencoding
\@onlypreamble\@setgeorgianencoding
\@onlypreamble\sce@a
\@onlypreamble\sce@b
\@onlypreamble\sce@c
\ifdefined\georgianencoding
\else
  \if@kauni@ode
    \def\georgianencoding{TU}
  \fi
  \else
    \edef\georgianencoding{T8M}
  \fi
  \PackageWarning{babel}%
    {No Georgian font encoding has been loaded so far.\MessageBreak
     A font encoding should be declared before babel.\MessageBreak
     Default `\georgianencoding' encoding will be loaded
    }%
  \lowercase\expandafter{\expandafter\input\georgianencoding enc.def\relax}%
  \AtBeginDocument{\@setgeorgianencoding}
\fi
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot...I'm author of georgian.ldf ...can you point where to look how to add TU encoding

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili It depends if you want to still support `EU1/EU2`; if not, change all their appearance into `TU`.

Comment: It does not help....somewhere in midle TU encoding is changed back to EU....this is from log file:...Sorry will add log output to question post

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili Doesn't happen to me.

Comment: Strange... does not work for me...I got warning missing bbl.cfg from arabi package..can this affect? OS:win10. Miktex. udated all packages from update manager

Comment: Sorry..somewhere another georgian.ldf was on a path :)

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili Please, contact me if you need some help to improve the Georgian style: http://www.texnia.com/contact.html (and then we could continue by e-mail).