# Georgian letters

Tags: alphabet

I need to write Georgian letters in my LaTeX document. Unfortunately I have no idea how computers work, and can just use my TeX because a friend installed it for me.

It seems I need a package (`\usepackage [language]{babel}`) but I don't think this package is in my computer (if that's the right expression).  I have absolutely no idea how to "get" a package or if I have it to make LaTeX "use" it.

Can anyone tell me how to proceed?

Thanks a lot in advance.

edit: it seems that I have babel, but not it's georgian setting.  For example, \usepackage [english]{babel} runs but replacing 'english' with 'georgian' doesn't compile and I gt an error:

exit code 1
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty:343: Package babel Error: You haven't specified a language option ...ry to proceed from here, type x to quit}

Also, if relevant, I have pdftex

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379899/babel-georgian-and-fontspec

Comment: you should have babel (and it's Georgian support) installed already as part of your tex system, but it is possible you installed a minimal version without Georgian, but that can easily be fixed. If the examples at the link in the previous comment do not work, edit your question to show the error that you get, and someone will help/

Comment: If you have TeX installed, then you almost certainly have the `babel` package.  What OS are you using?  Did your friend also install a TeX front end like TeXworks, MikTeX, or TeXshop?

Comment: That answer gives the error: I can't find file `t8menc.def'. ...fter\input\georgianencoding enc.def\relax} on my machine.

Comment: @SergeyBelyaev that error means that you used pdflatex, use xelatex (see also the xelatex example I posted below)

Comment: thanks for your answers!  unfortunately i'm still stuck.  it seems i have babel installed, but no georgian, or in fact any language aside from english.  by this i mean: if i command \usepackage [english]{babel} then it runs but if i replace 'english' with another language i get 'exit code 1' and 'you havent specified a language option' and another tex document opens.  

unfortunately i can't understand what the link you provided tells me to do.

Answer (score 5):

A basic example (process with `xelatex`) would be

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Segoe UI} % any font on your system I picked this as it's the
                      % font my browser used on the google translate page that
                      % I used to make the text below.

\usepackage[georgian]{babel}
\begin{document}

Გამარჯობა მსოფლიო

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get this error: `! Corrupted NFSS tables.
wrong@fontshape ...message {Corrupted NFSS tables}
                                                  error@fontshape else let f...
l.3 \babel@aux{georgian}{}` and it does not compile. It compiles without babel, though. But with larger text it fails to hyphenate anything. Hyphenation works with polyglossia (with `\setdefaultlanguage{georgian}`).

Comment: Just tested and works for me. No error and the text is hyphenated with `xetex`. Perhaps there is a problem with your installation (or it's old). Oddly, with this font it doesn't work for me with `luatex`, but others like FreeSerif and Deja Vu do.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე it should work on a current latex system, you could add the complete log that you get from this example to my answer, so we can debug.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stackexchange! Here is the output and the code you are to input in your (La)TeX processing program (like TeXStudio or TeXLive whichever you use and your friend installed for you):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mxedruli}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        {\Large\mxedc ve.pxis .tqaosani}
        \medskip
        {\large\mxedc +sota rustaveli}
    \end{center}
    \bigskip
    \begin{verse}
        \begin{mxedr}
            .gmertsa +semvedre, nutu .kvla damxsnas soplisa
            +sromasa,\\
            cecxls, .cqalsa da mi.casa, haerta tana +sromasa;\\
            momcnes prteni da a.gvprinde, mivhxvde mas +cemsa
            ndomasa,\\
            d.gisit da .gamit vhxedvide mzisa elvata .krtomasa.
            \medskip
            9
            mze u+senod ver ikmdebis, ratgan +sen xar masa .cili,\\
            gana.gamca mas eaxel misi e.tli, ar tu .cbili!\\
            muna gnaxo, madve gsaxo, ganminatlo guli +crdili,\\
            tu sicocxle m.care mkonda, si.kvdilimca mkonda .t.kbili!
        \end{mxedr}
    \end{verse}
\end{document}
```

This example was shamelessly stolen [from here](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/fonts/georgian/mxedruli/mxeddoc.pdf). Note, that I know no Georgian so I hope you will be able to make sense how they type in Georgian (looks phonetically for me).

I admit this being not exactly what you might have got used to (I mean typing Georgian directly), but after some googling it appears that Georgian is hard to type in Latex :)

Comment: If you had used xetex or luatex you could type directly in Georgian not via an ascii transliteration

Comment: I am afraid we would need to explain how to install xetex and luatex, then

Comment: It is rather hard to install latex without installing both those, even the most basic miktex or texlive has all three pdftex,xetex,luatex

Comment: Well, it is good to know. I thought I have texlivefull only. Wow, thank you for letting me know

Comment: I posted a xelatex version

Comment: thanks for the answer! it seems i don't have the package mxedruli, and i don't know how to make latex "use" packages if i manage to install it.

Comment: Just copy our examples into your TeX processing program (like TeXStudio, TeXLive or something) and compile it (press F5 for the software above). LaTeX will do the job and "use" everything it is supposed to use. If you provide more information about how you process your files and give the example file that compiles on your machine, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: copying your example gives me the error: 'finished with exit code 1, file mxedruli.sty not found'

Comment: I think I now have the package, but I don't know what to do with it.  I've managed to put it in a certain place (directory?) where my other tex files are, and then my latex document *does* compile with the package 'medruli'.  However, between \begin {mxedr} and \end {mxedr} any letters come out english (roman).  In other words, copying and pasting *exactly* your code gives me roman letters (and dots and pluses)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you use David Carlisle’s solution.  For completeness, there is also a pair of 8-bit font encodings compatible with PDFLaTeX, T8K and T8M.  To use them, install the [georgian](https://www.ctan.org/topic/georgian) and [babel-georgian](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel-georgian?lang=en) CTAN packages, and put in your preamble

```
\usepackage[T8M,T8K,T1]{fontenc}
```

Then select one of the few fonts that support it, such as DejaVu Georgian.  For example, this switches between DejaVu Serif in other languages, and DejaVu Georgian for Georgian.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm]{geometry} % Solely to format a MWE on TeX.SX

\usepackage[T8M,T8K,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{DejaVuSerif}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\usepackage[georgian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\substitutefont{T8M}{DejaVuSerif-TLF}{djg}
\substitutefont{T8K}{DejaVuSerif-TLF}{djg}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{georgian}
ვინაიდან ადამიანთა ოჯახის ყველა წევრისათვის დამახასიათებელი ღირსების და თანასწორი და განუყოფელი უფლებების აღიარება წარმოადგენს თავისუფლების, სამართლიანობის და საყოველთაო მშვიდობის საფუძველს; და

ვინაიდან, ადამიანის უფლებათა უგულებელყოფამ და აბუჩად აგდებამ გამოიწვია ბარბაროსული აქტები, რაც აღაშფოთებს კაცობრიობის სინდისს, და რომ ისეთი მსოფლიოს შექმნა, რომელშიც ადამიანებს ექნებათ სიტყვისა და რწმენის თავისუფლება, და რომელშიც ისინი იცხოვრებენ შიშისა და გაჭირვების გარეშე, გამოცხადებულია ადამიანთა მაღალ მისწრაფებად,
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

[image: Universal Declaration of Human Rights (Georgian)]